# How to add an amount of ether to function calling?

Tags: web3js, payable

I have a function in my contract, suppose

```
 function foo(uint _param1) payable {
     require(msg.value == 1000);
     someArray.push(x);
 }
```

Then I have my Javascript code:

```
 contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address); 
 contract.foo("Hello World!", function(err, res){
   alert("Transaction sent");
 });
```

Now, I have the web3 injected by Metamask, so I must use the asynchronous method because MetaMask doesn't support the synchronous method without the callback.
I have tried several ways to add an amount to my transaction, e.g. I've tried

```
 contract.foo("Hello World!",
   {from: web3.eth.coinbase, value: 1000}, 
   function(err, res){
    alert("Transaction sent");
   }
 );
```

but there is nothing that works!

So, how to solve it?

Comment: What you tried looks right to me. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: MetaMask opens the popup that asks the confirmation but the value is set equal to zero Ether.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, this is probably just a rounding error. The amount of you're sending is 1000 wei, which is 0.000000000000001 ether. From your description, it sounds like you're looking for the value in MetaMask, which I believe displays fewer decimal points than that.

Try sending a (much) higher value to confirm.

Comment: You are right... So stupid error...